# Actions name when exporting to FBX

Tags: animation, rigging, export, .fbx

I named my actions in the Action Editor. 01_Stop, 02_Walking and so on.. However, when I export my model and my animations (actions) to .fbx, the names are messed up, it adds the name of every parent the action has, something like Rig|Rig|02_Walking .

Is it possible to delete this while exporting ? I need to write the name manually in my code.

---

**Edit by other user:** I have posted a bounty on this question that is about to expire so in the interest of getting an answer, I am linking to a file whose exported .fbx has the behavior described by OP.

[image]

Comment: I am also dealing with this and it is getting ugly:
`root|root|GrabThrow|root|GrabThrow`
WTF???
Using 2.82. 2.83 doesn't render on my laptop for some reason

Comment: Can you add a .blend file that has this behavior to this question for convenience?

Comment: I posted the bounty but this isn't my question. I would need to edit it (intrusive, never tried before) or post a duplicate question